# Can inserting values from sub queries into table fail the insertion if the sub query returns nothing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following query in which I'm creating a temp table to extract and insert data into it from different tables and the record selected in looping it.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    --Only transactions found between the given start date and end date for the given events will be considered
  START_TIME_STR     VARCHAR := '2018-01-28 00:00:00';
  END_TIME_STR       VARCHAR := '2018-02-27 23:59:59';
  v_category         INTEGER := 2; 

BEGIN


  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cntr_track_detail (
    cntr_no      VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    cntr_trxn_id BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    surajbari    TEXT default null,
    mokha        TEXT default null,
    gate_in      TEXT default null,
    port_in      TEXT default null,
    terminal_in  TEXT default null,
    terminal_name VARCHAR(100) default null
  ) ON COMMIT DROP;


  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tranx1 ON COMMIT DROP AS select b.* from 
  (SELECT ctm.cntr_no,ctm.cntr_trxn_id FROM cntr_trxn_mapping ctm INNER JOIN cntr_track_time_log cttl 
    ON cttl.cntr_trxn_id = ctm.cntr_trxn_id AND ctm.cntr_cycle_id = v_category
    AND cttl.timestamp_gnrl >= start_time AND cttl.timestamp_gnrl <= end_time AND cttl.event_id in (13,21,1,19))b;

    raise notice 'size of tranx1 is,%', (select count(t.*) from tranx1 t);


  FOR v_intrim_loop IN (select distinct(t.*) from tranx1 t)
  LOOP
    BEGIN

      INSERT INTO cntr_track_detail (cntr_no, cntr_trxn_id, surajbari, mokha, gate_in, port_in, terminal_in, terminal_name) VALUES (v_intrim_loop.cntr_no, v_intrim_loop.cntr_trxn_id,
      (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1),

      (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1),


      (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1),


      (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1),


      (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1),

       (SELECT x from something LIMIT 1)
 );
 raise notice 'iteration ,%',iter;
 iter := iter +1;
    END;
  END LOOP;

END $$;
SELECT a.* FROM cntr_track_detail a ORDER BY a.cntr_no;
```

I'd like to ask if inserting this way will make the insertion fail for that iteration if the sub query returns nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `distinct(t.*)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct t.*`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. This was informative. Can you please point out if I will miss that row if the selected subqueries used in VALUES() return nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `distinct(t.*)` which removes the duplicate value and Maybe your table contains duplicate value so those are removed that's why you are getting fewer rows.

Comment: Yes, this was that. Could you please let me know if I'm doing insertion the right way? Will I miss that row if the selected subqueries used in VALUES return nothing?